# disable button if none of the options are selected angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I would like to disable the add button if none of the options in the list are selected or if the selected class is not there in the list.

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="json in myJson" ng-class="{'selected': json.selected}" ng-model="selectionOptions" ng-click="selectItem($index)">
  {{json.title}}
</div>
<button ng-disabled="hideAdd">Add</button>
```

I have tried:

```
 $scope.$watch('selectionOptions', function(val) {
    if(angular.element('selectionOptions').hasClass('selected')) {
        $scope.hideAdd = false;
    } else {
        $scope.hideAdd = true;
    }
  });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jvxfgt13/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use ng-model here, since there is no input.
You can watch the json or you can use a filter to determine if there are any selected elements. Example of the latter:

```
 .directive('appClick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      optionIsSelected();

      function optionIsSelected() {
        $scope.hideAdd = $scope.myJson.filter(function(el) {
          return el.selected
        }).length === 0;
      }

      $scope.selectItem = function(index) {
        $scope.myJson[index].selected = !($scope.myJson[index].selected);
        optionIsSelected();
      };
    }
  }
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svL5ymc4/)**

Answer (score 2):

No need for a directive or a $watch.

Remove the `ng-model` as it's doing nothing. Even if it did work every item would be bound to the same variable.

Use `ng-click` to call a function on `$scope` which toggles the selected value and adds/removes it from the list of selected options.

You can use `ng-show="selectedOptions.length"` to hide/show the add button.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myJson = [{
    title: 'test1',
    selected: false
  }, {
    title: 'test2',
    selected: true
  }, {
    title: 'test3',
    selected: false
  }, {
    title: 'test4',
    selected: false
  }];

  // Initialize array with already selected options
  $scope.selectedOptions = $scope.myJson.filter(function(item) {
    return item.selected;
  });

  $scope.toggle = function(item) {
    // Toggle selected
    item.selected = !item.selected;

    // Add it to list
    if (item.selected) {
      $scope.selectedOptions.push(item);
    } else {
      // Remove it from list
      $scope.selectedOptions.splice($scope.selectedOptions.indexOf(item), 1);
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  <div app-click="">
    <div ng-repeat="json in myJson" ng-click="toggle(json)" ng-class="{'selected': json.selected}">
      {{json.title}}
    </div>
    <button ng-show="selectedOptions.length">Add</button>
  </div>

  <br/>Selected options: <pre>{{selectedOptions | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: why do I have to add it to the list?

Comment: @user4756836 You need to maintain a list of `selectedOptions` so you can hide/show the "Add" button when there is at least one selected option. You can't bind the element to the array using `ng-model` so you need to add or remove the item when it is clicked. If you don't add it to the list, you won't know how many selected items there are.